# how can I make a jar file in opencv project elclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, opencv, jar

I am running my OpenCV project in eclipse successfully. I have added OpenCV-3.0.0 as my user library in my projects,but when I export a runnable jar file it can't be running in cmd windows (while the jar file of non-opencv projects run in cmd successfully). the [image below shows the error in running time of the jar file 
[image: cmd image]

I will be grateful for your guides.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem by copying the opencv_java300.dll file in the folder D:\OpenCV3.0.0\opencv\build\java\x86 to the folder c:\windows\system32.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the OpenCV lib pragmatically, you can try this:

```
public static void loadOpenCV_Lib() throws Exception {
    // get the model
    String model = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");
    // the path the .dll lib location
    String libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x86/";
    // check for if system is 64 or 32
    if(model.equals("64")) {
        libraryPath = "C:/opencv/build/java/x64/";
    }
    // set the path
    System.setProperty("java.library.path", libraryPath);
    Field sysPath = ClassLoader.class.getDeclaredField("sys_paths");
    sysPath.setAccessible(true);
    sysPath.set(null, null);
    // load the lib
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

Now when your program initiated, you call the method at the first, then it will work.

Hope it solves the problem!

Comment: Thank you for your help.